# Optimizing image sorting

Tags: sorting, optimization

I have a problem about optimizing image sorting
The input will be a list of the shape. It will have any shape or any area. How do I arrange these shapes in another large rectangle so that there is as little extra space as possible.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bApA1.png)

Comment: Since you didnt specify a language or program I'm going to have to keep it very abstract. 

A shape sorting algorithm could operate like this: 

Step 1: Count the num sides. If n_sides = 1, circle. n_sides = 3, triangle. If sides = 4, could be the other three shapes. 
Step 2: check side length. If all sides are equal, then its a square. 
Step 3: Check for curves. If all sides are straight, then rectangle. Else, that weird curvy shape.

Comment: @Parker.V: the question is about shape packing.

Comment: Such a packing problem is extremely arduous, especially in this general case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh yeah, it definitely seems like a difficult problem. It would be easier or harder depending on how the "shape" is stored in the list.

Comment: Even circles of the same radius in a rectangle is quite difficult.